# Select query to get particular pattern

Tags: mysql

I have a column which stores the data from the below format.
["12973","111","5555"].

I want to select the items which is not in the above set.
for ex,

If I search 12973 if it is exactly match it will not return.
When I use Like if I search "129" it also return the same result.

Any ideas to solve this problem..

Comment: So you want any row that does not contain 12973 in the first case and any row that does not contain a number starting with 129 in the second case? Also, what version of MySql is this for?

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for an exact number you can use NOT LIKE to exclude the row

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 NOT LIKE '%"12973"%'
```

if you are searching for a row where no numbers start with 129 you can use REGEXP

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE NOT col1 REGEXP '.*"129[0-9]*"'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about search all results with LIKE and remove the exact matches?

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE a LIKE '%129%' AND a != '129'
```